# React app - avoiding styles being overridden by other CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to provide some copy and paste code that shows a form on a user's website.

All of the elements are within "#myContainer".

However, the element styles are being overridden by other CSS on the user's page.

For example, I have a button with a class of `button.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-text.MuiButton-textPrimary.jss145`. I know I can target this as a descendant of `#myContainer` also.

But there are hundreds of possible ways a third party site can interfere with the CSS (eg. background color of fields, hover states of buttons) - none of which are specifically defined in my CSS.

Without specifically defining every single eventuality, is there a way I can prevent anything in `#myContainer` being interfered with by CSS outside?

Many thanks

Comment: Check out [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `css-modules` combined with scss to restrict css bleeding.

> index.scss

```
.mycontainer {
   :global {
       .button.MuiButtonBase-root {
           background: #CCCCCC;
       }
    }
}
```

> MyComponent.js

```
import styles from './index.scss';

const MyComponent = props => {
  return (
      <div className={styles.mycontainer}>
         <button className="button MuiButtonBase-root">Button</button>
      </div>
  );
};
```

This will produce a unique parent class name and same will be generated in css by css-loader.

```
 <div class="MyComponent__mycontainer-33ds2d3">
     <button className="button MuiButtonBase-root">Button</button>
 </div>
```

I don't know what will be the output format but will be similar to `MyComponent__mycontainer-33ds2d3` which will ensure that these styles will not bleed out and vice versa.

Add css-loader with `cssModules: true`

```
const autoPrefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssNesting = require('postcss-nested');


{
    test: /src\/(.*)\.(scss)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader',
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [autoPrefixer, postcssNesting(/* pluginOptions */)],
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the reply. This will stop CSS bleeding out, but the problem I'm trying to get past is I can't think of every possible property (eg. background-color, background-color on hover state...) that third party sites might set...

Comment: Can you explain your problem with example.

Comment: Sure - http://www.nearlyrealflorals.co.uk/testing-forms/ -  so the form under "This is where it shall go" is the React app. The fields should have a white backgorund. The h4 should be white. But these are being overwritten by the surrounding page (eg. input[type=text] ).

I could easily fix these by making a more specific CSS declaration (eg. #myapp h4 {color: white} ) BUT I can't think of every single variation, as if I paste the code on another site it will have different rules...

I need to be able to prevent the rest of the page intefering with everything inside my app container...

Comment: @HCapello Can you try setting style to `* {
   display: initial;
}` so it will not inherit